# Two smtproutes for one domain in qmail

Tags: email, email-server

We currently have a qmail set up as an email gateway for incoming mail, and from there it is routed to a different internal mail server based on smtproutes.

Is there a way that we can have one domain forwarded from the qmail 'gateway' to multiple internal servers? For example, when someone will send an email to user@example.com, it gets routed to our qmail server, and from there a copy is sent to both mailserver1.example.com and mailserver2.example.com - both of which have the same list of users and both of which think that they are the mailserver for example.com

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to route the message on the head server to a .qmail file and then in the .qmail file forward the message to user@mailserver1.example.com and user@mailserver2.example.com.  I think if you use the 'forward' program you could create a generic catch all that forwards all messages to the two servers.

/var/qmail/aliases/.qmail-default might look like this:

```
|forward "$LOCAL@mailserver1.example.com" "$LOCAL@mailserver2.example.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try to see if I can implement it within our setup.

Answer (score 1):

*Both*? Probably not, at least with stock qmail. If you're happy to recompile qmail, you can define `QUEUE_EXTRA` to anything you like, and then route the local ones to a second local server.